# How to share folder in ubuntu server for windows users, everyone?

Tags: samba

I have started samba daemon on ubuntu server 9.04 with following config:

```
[share]
  comment = Share
  read only = no
  path = /share
  guest ok = yes
```

Windows users can browse share, but can't create / copy / modify files in it :(. How to give everyone a full access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba still uses the underlying Unix permissions, so none of the users who are connecting can likely write to that directory.

One way to do it would be to use the force user directive:

```
force user = <username>
```

Use the username that owns `/share`.

If you still want the files owned by the actual user that created them, then you could use

```
force group = group
create mask 0775
```

This will make sure all files are in the same group and that group read/write permissions are assigned to everything that is created.